# How to combine Notion Timesheets for TFS 2010 and TFS 2012?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

We have TFS 2010 and TFS 2012 set up. We would like to have [notion timesheets](http://www.imaginet.com/Solutions/ALM/Pages/Notion-Timesheet.aspx) display work items from both TFS 2010 and TFS 2012.

We are not scheduled to migrate from 2010 to 2012 for a while so I was wondering if we could just change the stored procedure to pull the data from **both** TFS 2010 and TFS 2012 databases.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From the above link it seems that Notion Timesheets integrate with the SSAS cubes in TFS via the TFS Reporting Warehouse Service. Perhaps you can just use a different url?